# Question about command to execute when running Jenkins image

Tags: jenkins

I have questions while using the Jenkins image to check the commands to run the container and leave a question.

I ran the following command.

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  --name jenkins \
  -v /Users/newbie/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkins:lts
```

What does **' : '** and ' **-v** ' mean in `-v /Users/newbie/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home \` on line 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-v = Bind mount a volume. See [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only)

It mounts `/Users/newbie/jenkins` directory on your host to `/var/jenkins_home` on your container

Comment: So what does the colon mean?

Comment: That's part of syntax to separate out the host path to container path when mounting

Comment: Is it possible to omit the colon?

Comment: Why do you want to omit it ?

Comment: It's a simple curiosity!